# Angular dynamic background-image without ngStyle

Tags: css, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm working on an AngularUniversal application that allows users to view a gallery of photos dynamically.
The problem is that SEO penalizes me because I have inline-css, it is because I have the following in my code

```
<div *ngFor="let c of covers" class="item-cover-image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + c.cover +')'}">
</div>
```

and when rendering with SSR it translates like this

```
<div class="item-cover-image" style="background-image: url(https://mystite/gallery/01.jpg)">
</div>
```

Is there a way to dynamically render the images in my gallery without ngStyle or inline-css?

Comment: maybe you can use img tag?

Comment: image tags do not maintain aspect ratio. There are longer and/or wider photographs and the frame by which each image is presented is 150px x 150px